# Audio HTML5 with fallback to Flash - Play/pause the music with Flash on IE8?

Tags: flash, audio, internet-explorer-8, html5-audio

I use HTML5 audio with a fallback to Flash for IE8. Is it possible to play and pause the music when Flash is used?

Thanks for your help!

Here is my code for the audio:

```
<audio>
<source src="musique.mp3">
<object  type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://player.longtailvideo.com/player.swf">
    <param name="audio" value="http://player.longtailvideo.com/player.swf" /> 
    <param name="flashvars" value="autostart=true&amp;file=musique.mp3" />
</object>
</audio>
```